# A program developed in C language can know which OS is compiling it?

Tags: c, operating-system

I'm developing an API multi platform in C language and I need to know if there is a way to know which OS is compiling it.

For example, through an pre compilation directive like that follows:

```c
#ifdef LINUX
#include<linuxlib.h>
#elif OSX
#include<osxlib.h>
#elif WINDOWS
#include<rwindowslib.h>
```

Comment: why would you need to know that? Maybe there's something else that you can use?

Comment: Note that TARGET_OS_MAC can be used for OSX.

Comment: "Executing" -- you mean "compiling", right?

Comment: for more info try this: `echo | gcc -E -dM -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some info:

```
#if defined(__LINUX__)
// Linux, Android, MacOS
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
// Android
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
// MacOS
#else
// Linux or its flavor
#endif
#elif defined(WIN32)
// Windows targets must have WIN32 (_WIN32)
#endif
```

Here is a large list of what can be defined on various platforms:
http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

Comment: This works fine for linux and mac os, i not tested the Windows

Comment: @LuizFilipe _WIN32 macro is mandated by Microsoft for Win API builds. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx